# How to implement this code in c# 5.0

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test1
{
    public class NewGenerics<T> where T:new(int)
    {

    }
}
```

How do I correctly write this code so that it compiles with C# 5.0?

Comment: Not possible, only new() is supported

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rkrahl: Obviously, the OP is asking for a way to place a generic constraint that requires `T` to have a constructor that takes an `int` value.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Clear to you maybe.

Comment: @Oded: Sorry, I'm usually all for a detailed and verbose explanation instead of pure source code, but when `new()`, namely `new`, the keyword for calling a constructor, and `()`, an empty parameter list, requiring a *constructor* with an *empty parameter list*, is modified to `new(int)`, i.e. `new`, the keyword for calling a constructor, and `(int)`, a parameter list with an `int`, I think it is pretty straightforward how to interpret this. Anything else, such as `new-int` or `new[[int]]`, and I wouldn't have considered it that clear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to cheat/workaround and make it with new() and an interface to set the integer value:

```
namespace Test1
{
    public class NewGenerics<T> where T: IMyInterface, new()
    {
         private static T Create(int theInteger)
         {
              var inst = new T();
              inst.SetTheInteger(theInteger);
              return inst;
         }


         ....
    }
}
```

You could use the Create method to create instances and initialize them with the integer or whatever values you need..

If you can enforce that all of the types implement the specific interface that is..

Comment: The `int` field in `T` cannot be declared as `readonly` in that case, though, which is occasionally desired for values that are (only ever) set in the constructor.

Comment: thus the "cheat/workaround".. it is not possible to create this constraint, so all solutions are workarounds..

Comment: Sure, just thought it's important that disadvantages be pointed out along with each workaround, so the OP has a better base for his/her decision. If that interface can be implemented as suggested by you, yours is of course a good solution that even allows for compile-time checking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the supported set of generic constraints in current C# versions do not allow to specify any required constructor signatures other than a parameterless constructor.

The only way to accomplish this would be a runtime check using reflection. You can use the [`GetType()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) to retrieve `T`'s [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) instance and then use [`GetConstructors()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructors.aspx) to retrieve [`ConstructorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.aspx) instances for all constructors. Using those, you can check whether any of the constructors in `T` has the desired signature and throw an exception otherwise ... in each constructor of your `NewGenerics<T>` class.

The drawback of this solution is that it's only checked at runtime; it will still compile happily and throw only once someone tries to create an instance of your class.